# Переменная $_POST недоступна для вывода на стороне сервера

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, ajax

- Сайт на wordpress
- Посылаю ajax запрос методом `POST` через `XMLHttpRequest` не через форму а просто руками вбиваю параметры и делаю запрос сюда: http://dpk/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=dpkhook
- На стороне сервера вывожу: `echo json_encode($_POST);`
- Смотрю результат этого вывода здесь: http://dpk/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=dpkhook
- Результат вывода: `[]` - пустой массив
- В тело ajax запроса передаю параметры так: `let params = 'myname=' + 'y est' + '&' + 'myname2' + 'grut';`
- На фронте (произвольная страница, где js-скрипт отрабатывает) получаю ответ от сервера:

```
{
  myname: 'y est',
  myname2: 'grut'
}
```

*Если сделать проверку на стороне сервера типо:

```
if ($_POST['myname'] && $_POST['myname']=='y est') {
  echo json_encode("DA");
} else {
  echo json_encode("NET");
}
```

то на стороне сервера (на странице http://dpk/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=dpkhook) выводится `"NET"`,
а на фронт ответ от сервера приходит `"DA"`

*Если на стороне сервера состряпать запрос типа: `$query = new WP_Query( $args );`, то `$query` на стороне сервера выводится. `$_GET` тоже выводится: `{"action":"dpkhook"}`

**Вопрос:** почему переменную `$_POST` я на стороне сервера не могу вывести? `$_POST['myname']`, `$_POST['myname2']` на стороне сервера тоже не выводятся. Это ограничение самого wp что ли, или `$_POST` теряется где-то по дороге?

P.S. `file_get_contents("php://input");` не помогло

P.P.S. Код js и php:

```js
"use strict";

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", pageLoadedHandler);

function pageLoadedHandler() {
  console.log('завершена загрузка и построение DOM документа');

    let params = 'myname=' + 'y est' + '&' + 'myname2=' + 'grut';
    let my_url = myPlugin.ajaxurl + '?action=dpk2hook';
    ajaxPost(my_url, params);

}

function ajaxPost(url, params) {
  let request = new XMLHttpRequest();

  request.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (request.readyState == 4 && request.status == 200) {
      console.log(request.response);
    }
  }
  request.open('POST', url);
  request.responseType = 'json';
  request.setRequestHeader( 'Content-Type', 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded' );
  request.send(params);

}
```

```html
<?php
/**
 * Plugin Name: Ajax запросы для фильтра записей wpforms
 */
add_action('wp_ajax_dpk2hook', 'say_hello');
//для запросов от авторизованных пользователей используется хук wp_ajax_'nazvanie action'

function say_hello() {

  echo json_encode($_POST);

  wp_die();
}

add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_asset', 9999 );
function my_asset() {
  if (is_page( 2299 )) {
    wp_enqueue_script('custom', plugins_url('custom.js', __FILE__), [], '1_4');

    wp_localize_script('custom', 'myPlugin', [
      'ajaxurl' => admin_url('admin-ajax.php'),
    ]); 
  }
}
```

Comment: Покажите js код отправки xhr. Есть такое чувство, что параметры вы через `get` передаёте. И посмотрите в сторону [fetch](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch).

Comment: @nazarpunk та не, через POST делаю: ```request.open('POST', url);``` с fetch пока не хотелось бы связываться, т.к. поддержка у него 96%, знаю что поддержку полифилами можно пофиксить, но пока этот инструментарий не освоил

Comment: Добавьте нормальный воспроизводимый код отправки запроса и обработки на сервере

Comment: @alenkins добавил

Comment: @freestyle_HD поддержка `XMLHttpRequest` - `96.95%`, аж на `.95%` больше.  Избавьтесь от `say_hello()` и сразу сделайте  `echo json_encode($_POST);  wp_die();`, чтоб понимать данные не доходят или `wp` мудрит.

Comment: @nazarpunk я попробовал и через ```fetch``` и через ```jQuery```, результат тот же. Без ```say_hello()``` wordpress_error вылетает - не вариант. Видимо, это ограничение самого wordpress, что на стороне сервера именно на странице c ```ajaxurl```?action=hookname напрямую нельзя вывести переменную ```$_POST```, где ```ajaxurl``` - это ```admin_url('admin-ajax.php')```

Answer (score 0):

Мне так кажется, что просто мелкий косяк не дает правильно отправить данные на сервер. Вы говорите, что данные url-encoded, но где же они encoded?

```
myname=y est&myname2=grut
// вот это url-encoded
myname=y%20est&myname2=grut
```

Вполне возможно, что метод send() просто не может это отправить.